# Function in Haskell not getting generic type parameter

Tags: haskell

In Haskell I have the following

```
data Box a = Box a deriving Show

instance Functor Box where
  fmap func (Box a) = Box (func a)

box :: Box Int
box = Box 8

wrapped :: Box (Box Int)
wrapped = Box <$> box

unwrap :: (Box a) -> a
unwrap (Box val) = val
```

In GHCi I can call `fmap` with `unwrap wrapped` and I get `Box 8`, which I would expected.

```
*Main> fmap unwrap wrapped
Box 8
```

When I call `fmap` with `unwrap box` I get error about the types not matching, but I was thinking I would get the value 8.

```
*Main> fmap unwrap box

<interactive>:26:13: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Box b’
      Expected type: Box (Box b)
        Actual type: Box Int
    • In the second argument of ‘fmap’, namely ‘box’
      In the expression: fmap unwrap box
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = fmap unwrap box
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: Box b (bound at <interactive>:26:1)
```

I would have expected `fmap unwrap box` would give the value `8`.

How would I define `unwrap` to be able to get the value of `Box 8` for `wrapped` and `8` for `box` when using `fmap`?

I do not think it matters but I am using GHCi version 8.8.4

Comment: `fmap` unwraps the value `x` from the `Box` constructor, and then puts the *result* of `f x` *back* into a `Box`. So you can not use `unwrap` here, since `fmap f box`, will pas `8` to the function, and `unwrap` does not expect an `Int`, but a `Box b` object.

Comment: You can however use `unwrap wrapped` to obtain `Box 8`, and `unwrap box` to obtain `8`. There is no need for `fmap`.

Comment: `fmap any_function any_boxed_value` can never produce an `Int` like `8`, but only a value of type `Box b` for some `b`. That's how `fmap` is defined.

Comment: Note that `Box (Box 8)` is equivalent to `Box <$> (Box 8)`; `wrapped` does't actually require `Box` to be a functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `box = Box 8` and want to get a plain `8`, you should just call `unwrap box`, not `fmap unwrap box`. In general, `fmap` will never let you unwrap a value because its type `(Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` specifies that the result of `fmap x y` will have the wrapped type `f b`. Let's walk through the types to see why this happens:

When we call `fmap unwrap`, we can "unify" the type of `unwrap` with the type of the first argument to `fmap`, which gives us this specialized type for `fmap`:

```
fmap   :: (Functor f) => (a     -> b) -> f a       -> f b
unwrap ::                 Box a -> a
fmap   :: (Functor f) => (Box a -> a) -> f (Box a) -> f a
```

Notice that because `f` doesn't appear in the type of the first argument of `fmap`, `Box` doesn't fill in for `f`. We can then apply `unwrap` to this specialized version of `fmap`:

```
fmap unwrap :: (Functor f) => f (Box a) -> f a
```

This is almost certainly not the type you're expecting here. When we unify this for the argument `Box (Box 8)`, we get the specialized type:

```
fmap unwrap :: (Functor f) => f   (Box a  ) -> f   a
Box (Box 8) ::                Box (Box Int)
fmap unwrap ::                Box (Box Int) -> Box Int
```

But when we try to unify this with the type of argument `Box 8`, we run into a problem:

```
fmap unwrap :: (Functor f) => f   (Box a) -> f   a
Box 8       ::                Box Int
```

I can't match the type of `Box 8` with the expected argument to `fmap unwrap` because `Int` doesn't match the type `Box a`.

Comment: Thank you @andrew-ray this is an amazing response.  It makes perfect sense written out like this.

Comment: @MikeHarris The best part is that this unification process is pretty much what the compiler does, which is why my conclusion "`Int` doesn't match the type `Box a`" is similar to the error you got from the compiler "`Couldn't match type 'Int' with 'Box b'`." (Ignore the different name for the type variable; there's no meaningful difference between `a` and `b` here.)